# Can't enable EnableExecuteCommand in ECS service blue/green

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, blue-green-deployment, ecs-taskdefinition

I have a ECS service (blue/green) and i would like to exec containers then i tried to enable the `EnableExecuteCommand` in this service using aws cli:

`aws ecs update-service --cluster **** --task-definition **** --service **** --enable-execute-command`

but im getting:

`An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: Unable to update task definition on services with a CODE_DEPLOY deployment controller. Use AWS CodeDeploy to trigger a new deployment.`

it tell to create a new deployment but this does not make sense, i searched alot in google but can't find any solution, maybe it is not possible ? cuz the blue/green is managed by aws codedeploy ?

I found in aws docs this:

`For services using the blue/green (CODE_DEPLOY) deployment controller, only the desired count, deployment configuration, health check grace period, task placement constraints and strategies, enable ECS managed tags option, and propagate tags can be updated using this API. If the network configuration, platform version, task definition, or load balancer need to be updated, create a new AWS CodeDeploy deployment. For more information, see CreateDeployment in the AWS CodeDeploy API Reference.`
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateService.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

I thought maybe i could set it in taskdef.json but there is no EnableExecuteCommand property.

Could someone give me some hint?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's an ECS service-level setting, not a task definition setting. It requires a redeployment to change the setting, which is why it isn't letting you update the setting directly, since you are using CodeDeploy to perform the deployments. Unfortunately, it appears that the CodeDeploy AppSpec file doesn't support this setting currently, so I don't think there is any way to enable it.

Comment: I think you have to create an ECS service first, with the setting already enabled. Then change the deployment type to CodeDeploy.

Comment: @MarkB you mean that i need to create a new service with Deployment type Rolling Update then update it via aws cli to blue/green (codedeploy)?

Comment: Yes, or temporarily change the deployment type of your current service, if that is possible. I don't have a CodeDeploy project I can test this with at the moment, so I'm not sure what is possible.

Comment: @MarkB I think this is not possible cuz aws ecs update-service has not this option according to https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.1.21/reference/ecs/update-service.html, there is only a  deploymentController when using --cli-input-json.

Comment: Maybe I will need to find another way to exec these containers.

Comment: This tutorial shows creating the service first, before using CodeDeploy with the service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorial-ecs-prereqs.html At the point of creating the service, you could enable the ECS Exec setting.

Comment: I hope soon aws can make it more easy ;p

Comment: @MarkB if u want post it as answer then i can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way currently to enable that setting for an ECS service once it is configured to use CodeDeploy.

[This tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorial-ecs-prereqs.html) for ECS and CodeDeploy shows creating the service first, before using CodeDeploy with the service. At the point of creating the service, you could enable the ECS Exec setting.